# Firebase Analytics app version name is sometimes versionName and sometimes versionCode

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

In my Android App I am using Firebase Analytics for tracking. I see a strange behavior how my app version is tracked.

It should use my versionName from my app build.gradle but almost 50% of my traffic seem to be tracked with the versionCode

```
 defaultConfig {
    ...
    versionCode 99999
    versionName "1.0"
    ...
}
```

In Google Analytics the resulting page views are looking like this:

[screen shot analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRf7g.png)

My implementation for Firebase Analytics is short:

```
public class FirebaseTracker implements AbstractTracker {

private final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;

/**
 * Instantiates a new Firebase tracker.
 *
 * @param context the context
 */
public FirebaseTracker(Context context) {
    analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);
}

@Override
public void enableTracking(boolean enable) {
    analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(enable);
}

@Override
public void logEvent(String parameter, Bundle values) {
    analytics.logEvent(parameter, values);
}
```

}

I do not set any version code/name through `analytics.logEvent(..)`. They are obtained from Firebase SDK itself.

I hope someone had a similar behavior and can help me out. Or is it possible to force Firebase to use a specific app version through a config.xml?

Comment: Update:
It is not a firebase Issue. I reported this bug to them and they figured out that our app is sending the app versions correctly. It seem to be a problem while translating firebase to google tag manager keys

Comment: Do you find any solution/work around for this?